# How do the MAX endstops work?

Tags: marlin, endstop, axis

I’m building my new 3D printer and I have a doubt. I’m using limit switches on the 3 axes, but only the MIN switches. I also have another three switches which I want to use as MAX switches. How can I do that? I mean, if I insert a specific measure of the plate in Marlin and than the extruded stops before of the limit of the plate due to the MAX endstop what will happen? What should I do, upgrade to MIN and MAX endstops or only keep the MIN ones?

Comment: Most boards lack contacts for MAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see MAX endstops similarly as MIN endstops, or as an additional option to protect the printer:

1. Similarly seen as MIN endstops, you would define in the firmware that you are using them to set a reference point at maximum values, your offsets and bed dimensions would be calculated from the MAX positions;
2. You can configure the MIN endstops and have additional MAX endstops set beyond the bed size dimensions. If the printer would encounter a layer shift causing the nozzle to go beyond the printer (MAX) boundaries, the printer shuts down when the MAX endstop is triggered.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So i can’t use both of them in one axis? I think i’m going to use only the MIN ones

Comment: @Valeri0S As explained in the answer under 2. You can use them both. But don't put them at exactly at the maximum axis positions according the bed size, put them a little further, then they will act as safety stops in case of layer shifting occurrences.